# Class Library (UWP) unit test not being run

Tags: c#, unit-testing, uwp, class-library

I created a new Class Library (UWP) project set it up for unit tests (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34175226/3609052 for how I set it up).

Everything builds find and the tests show up, but when I right click and run the tests it builds and doesn't do anything.  They don't run.

Here is my setup:
[image: unit test setup]

Comment: Show the actual test code as a [mcve] . It is almost impossible for use to help with just an image.

Comment: UWP tests run inside an app container for the tests. Try and deploy your test project before you run the tests. Also could you include a pictures of the steps you went through to create the test project?

Comment: I found that out.  I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem. The unit tests require a runner, which means I must have a Unit Test Project. I found this in the output.